# Javascript not following step by step instruction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html

```js
$(function(){
    $(".button1").on("click",function(){
        $(".img").css("display","block");
        $(".bord").append('<div class="test1">11111111</div>');
        $(".img").css("display","none");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         
<div class="parent">
     <div class="button1">button1</div>
     <div class="button2">button2</div>
</div>
            
<div class="bord">
     <img src="http://www.mtlexs.com/images/reload.gif" class="img" style="display: none;">
 </div>
```

Here i write the code , when button1 click show image, then display text, then hide image . But here image is not showing

Then i change the code so show image and display text , and it is working

```js
 $(function(){
       $(".button1").on("click",function(){
             $(".img").css("display","block");
             $(".bord").append('<div class="test1">11111111</div>');
       });   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
      <div class="button1">button1</div>
      <div class="button2">button2</div>
</div>
                
<div class="bord">
      <img src="http://www.mtlexs.com/images/reload.gif" class="img" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

So what is the problem in my first code  ?

I need to    `show image->show text-->hide image`

Please check .

Comment: You're hiding the image immediately after you show text. You'll have to add a timer if you want the image to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the value of `display` to quicky. If you add a timeout you will see that the image is actually showing then hidding.

The change are not directly rendered (See @Maximus's answer)

Add a timeout and it will work as you want

```js
$(function() {

  $(".button1").on("click", function() {

    $(".img").css("display", "block");
    $(".bord").append('<div class="test1">11111111</div>');
    setTimeout(
      function() {
            $(".img").css("display", "none");
      }, 2000);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="button1">button1</div>
  <div class="button2">button2</div>
</div>

<div class="bord">
  <img src="http://www.mtlexs.com/images/reload.gif" class="img" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: _It is just to fast to see it._ - it's not fast, it's not rendered at all. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40483322/2545680) for details

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562390/jquery-function-is-not-working-due-to-document-ready

Comment: @John This is not revelant

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the `.img`, a browser needs to go through reflow and repaint process and it's possible only when callstack is empty (your code is not running).
This means that when you put the following:

```
$(".img").css("display","block");
```

The `.img` is not yet rendered on the screen, because the call stack is still busy and so a browser does nothing and waits for your code to finish executing. Then you put this code

```
$(".img").css("display","none");
```

And this returns to the previous state. When your code is finished executing, no reflow or repaint process happens at all. And you don't see your button on the screen.