# Jquery function is not working due to $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

we have two js fie , test-1.js , test-2.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test-2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test-1.js"></script>
```

In test-1.js the code is

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     function test_alert(){  alert("hiii");  }
        });
```

In test-2.js

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    function test_alert_2(){
          test_alert();
          alert("helloo");
        }

      });
```

but test_alert() not working in test-2.js . How to solve this ? Why this is not working ?

to solve this i rearranged

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test-2.js"></script>
```

Now also , it is not working.I can not remove **document.ready()**.

> So i need a solution without removing document.ready()

Please help.

Comment: is `test_alert()` working ?

Comment: yes. It is working

Answer (score 1):

call **test-1.js** before **test-2.js** .

**Example**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test-2.js"></script>
```

Comment: dont create function in $(document).ready(function(){ });   create function outside of it and if you want to run function then $(document).ready(function (){
      test_alert();
        });

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use code from `test-1.js` in `test-2.js` you have to load `test-1.js` first. JavaScript executes sequentially for synchronous code. So you can not access code from another scope (e.g. a file) if that code has not already been executed.

Comment: You've changed the code of the files, so this is *technically* a different question now...

Answer (score 0):

Adding this second answer because you changed the order to be correct, but then also changed the contents of the scripts. Since they both contain a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` where you create the functions, this means the functions you create only exist in the scope of that function, e.g.

```js
function foo() { 
  return 1;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // this is a new scope, functions created here will not be accessible outside of it.
  function bar() {
    return 2;
  }
});

foo(); // 1
bar(); // Error: undefined is not a function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two JavaScript files and you are using a function in test-2.js file which is present in test-1.js file.Your test_alert function is not working because you called that functin before the js file completely loaded,Due to the file loading delay your test_alert() is not working.

Now ,you can use window.setTimeout() to solve this problem.
 Like:-

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    function test_alert_2(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            test_alert();
            alert("helloo");   
        },1000);

    }

});
```

Through this code the test_alert() will be called after one second of script load.
I thing this Will Help You.